# Unlocked packages dont support standardValueSets so why is package version creation failing without standardValueSet folder?

Tags: standard-objects, unlocked-package, versioning

I have an unlocked package that has standardValueSet folder and we are able to create versions just fine. As part of technical debt I want to remove standardValueSet folder as it is not packageable according to salesforce metadata coverage. When I remove it and try to create package version I get:

```
WorkOrder.Appraisal_Pickup: Picklist value: Critical_Customer_Service in picklist: Priority not found
```

My Appraisal_Pickup record Type:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RecordType xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fullName>Pickup</fullName>
    <active>true</active>
    <label>Pickup</label>
    <picklistValues>
        <picklist>Priority</picklist>
        <values>
            <fullName>Critical_Customer_Service</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <picklist>Status</picklist>
        <values>
            <fullName>Assigned</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Canceled</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Closed</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Completed</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Confirmed</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Delayed</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Delayed%2FReassign</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>In Progress</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>New</fullName>
            <default>true</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Requested</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Scheduled</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
    </picklistValues>
</RecordType>
```

My standardValueSet that I removed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StandardValueSet xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <sorted>false</sorted>
    <standardValue>
        <fullName>Normal</fullName>
        <default>true</default>
        <label>Normal</label>
    </standardValue>
    <standardValue>
        <fullName>High (Multiple Attempts)</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>High (Multiple Attempts)</label>
    </standardValue>
    <standardValue>
        <fullName>Critical_Customer_Service</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>Critical (Customer Service)</label>
    </standardValue>
</StandardValueSet>
```

I have tried putting those in unpackaged folder within the unlocked package using unpackagedMetadata and same result. For my package version to be built, I have to leave standardValueSet folder in my package directory. That is contradictory to what Salesforce says and is a bit confusing.